# Как выполнить скрипт через ssh передав ему get параметры

Tags: php, shell

Запускаю выполнение скрипта командой:

```
/opt/php71/bin/php /folder/script.php
```

но нужно еще передать GET значения. Пробовал так:

```
/opt/php71/bin/php /folder/script.php?get1=val1&get2=val2
```

но не работает так, пишет что файл не найден

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4186392/4827341

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через консоль не получится передавать GET-параметры, поскольку & в консоли имеет другой смысл. В данном случае нужно модифицировать код самого скрипта.

В консоли:

```
/opt/php71/bin/php /folder/script.php val1 val2
```

В скрипте:

```
<?php

$_GET['get1'] = $argv[1]; // Получит первый аргумент - val1
$_GET['get2'] = $argv[2]; // Получит второй аргумент - val2
...
```